# Chaining Multiple CSS Animations on SVG in Infinite Loop

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have two animated svg's, with two separate animations. I would like to chain them (and maybe more in the future) — infinite on one element. I would prefer CSS only.

I have tried to chain them like this question [Chaining Multiple CSS Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004919/chaining-multiple-css-animations), but it seems that it is harder with the infinite loop — or there might be something wrong with my @keyframes (too simple).

The code can be found here: https://codepen.io/Miet/pen/bWWONo

The HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<div class="svg-container">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 35 22" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32.4 21.7;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <path class="st0" d="M2.5,13.2c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4C-0.1,12.1,1.1,13.2,2.5,13.2"
                />
            <path class="st0" d="M29.9,13.2c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4
                C27.3,12.1,28.4,13.2,29.9,13.2"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M8,7.2c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4C5.4,6.2,6.5,7.2,8,7.2"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M24.4,7.2c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4C21.8,6.2,23,7.2,24.4,7.2"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M16.2,21.6c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4
                C13.6,20.5,14.8,21.6,16.2,21.6"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M16.2,4.9c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4C13.6,3.8,14.8,4.9,16.2,4.9"/>
        </g>

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="10.853" x2="32.3588" y2="10.853">
            <stop  offset="0.2597" style="stop-color:#EE3251"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F47529"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <polyline class="st1" points="16.2,2.5 24.4,4.9 2.5,10.9 8.1,4.8 16.2,19.2 30.1,10.8 "/>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="svg-container">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 35 22" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32.4 21.7;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
            <path class="st0" d="M2.5,13.2c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4C-0.1,12.1,1.1,13.2,2.5,13.2"
                />
            <path class="st0" d="M29.9,13.2c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4
                C27.3,12.1,28.4,13.2,29.9,13.2"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M8,7.2c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4C5.4,6.2,6.5,7.2,8,7.2"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M24.4,7.2c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4C21.8,6.2,23,7.2,24.4,7.2"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M16.2,21.6c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4
                C13.6,20.5,14.8,21.6,16.2,21.6"/>
            <path class="st0" d="M16.2,4.9c1.4,0,2.6-1.1,2.6-2.4c0-1.3-1.1-2.4-2.6-2.4c-1.4,0-2.6,1.1-2.6,2.4C13.6,3.8,14.8,4.9,16.2,4.9"/>
        </g>

        <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="10.853" x2="32.3588" y2="10.853">
            <stop  offset="0.2597" style="stop-color:#EE3251"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F47529"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <polyline class="st2" points="16.2,2.5 24.4,4.9 2.5,10.9 8.1,4.8 16.2,19.2 30.1,10.8 "/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    svg {
        width: 20em;
        display: block;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 1rem;
    }

    .svg-container {
        width: 49%;
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 21em;
    }


    g {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .st0 {
        fill:#EE3251;
    }

    .st1,
    .st2 {
        stroke-dasharray: 60;
        fill: none;
        stroke: url(#SVGID_1_);
        stroke-width: 5;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }

    .st1 {
        animation: dash 4s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
    }

    .st2 {
        animation: dashLong 2500ms infinite linear;
    }

    @keyframes dash {
        from {
            stroke-dashoffset: 200;
        }
    }

    @keyframes dashLong {
        from {
            stroke-dashoffset: 120;
        }
    }
```

Comment: chaining means one starts when the other finishes. If they are infinite that's not going to do much so you'll need to describe the effect you're looking for more clearly.

Comment: @RobertLongson I would like to start with animation 1 — followed with animation 2 — then start over with animation 1 followed by animation 2 again ... and so on. So this is not possible?

Comment: animation 1 runs forever so how can you start animation 2 when animation 1 finishes?

Comment: I see. I will have to find an other way. Thank you for your reply!