# How to repeat svg animation with different color on each loop?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a svg animation like the below, its repeating 3 times, but i want to draw the animation 3 different colors in each time. Below is the fiddle.

Fiddle - jsfiddle.net/6fyg1msL/4

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple. Just use 3 different keyframes as follows:

Your SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
<path class="path1" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="550" stroke-dashoffset="550" d="M240,260c0,6.627-5.373,12-12,12h-76c-6.627,0-12-5.373-12-12v-76
    c0-6.627,5.373-12,12-12h76c6.627,0,12,5.373,12,12V260z"/>
<path class="path2" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="550" stroke-dashoffset="550" d="M271,296c0,6.627-5.373,12-12,12h-76c-6.627,0-12-5.373-12-12v-76
    c0-6.627,5.373-12,12-12h76c6.627,0,12,5.373,12,12V296z"/>
<path class="path3" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="550" stroke-dashoffset="550" d="M306,346c0,6.627-5.373,12-12,12h-76c-6.627,0-12-5.373-12-12v-76
    c0-6.627,5.373-12,12-12h76c6.627,0,12,5.373,12,12V346z"/>
</svg>
```

And here is your CSS *(just the paths and keyframes)*

```
.path1 {
  animation: draw1 8.5s linear 3 forwards;  
}

 @keyframes draw1 {

  0%   
  {
    stroke: #b3s18c;

  }
    25%  {stroke:red;}
    50%  {stroke: blue;}
    75%  {stroke:green;}
    100% {stroke: Yellow;fill:none;stroke-dashoffset:100; }
}

.path2 {
  animation: draw2 8.5s linear 3 forwards;  
}

 @keyframes draw2 {

  0%   
  {
    stroke: #b3s18c;

  }
    25%  {stroke:green;}
    50%  {stroke: yellow;}
    75%  {stroke:red;}
    100% {stroke: blue;fill:none;stroke-dashoffset:100; }
}

.path3 {
  animation: draw3 8.5s linear 3 forwards;  
}

 @keyframes draw3 {

  0%   
  {
    stroke: #b3s18c;

  }
    25%  {stroke:blue;}
    50%  {stroke: green;}
    75%  {stroke:yellow;}
    100% {stroke: red;fill:none;stroke-dashoffset:100; }
}
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response dear Lynx, But i don't mean that... I want all to be red in first loop, then all to be blue in second loop, and all to be green in third loop... etc ...

Comment: Then you have to use `animation-delay`. Here is a good start for that:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004919/chaining-multiple-css-animations

Comment: I can use jquery i think, i can set  var iterationcount = $('.path').css("animation-iteration-count"); and then loop that, But the loop is not working with me. How can i create that loop ? So in each loop i can change the animation class.